# C# - Only set a the value of a variable if some other variable is not null

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am creating a list from a DataTable. Some cell values in the Datatable are null and hence I'm getting an error while running the conversion. I tried to achieve this using a 'ternary conditional operator', but that requires an 'else' clause too. I want to skip assigning a value to the variable if the cell value is null.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Are your integers (or whatever variable type you are having trouble on) nullable?

Comment: The variable have to be declared in most cases as int? (the question mark allows nulls).  In some cases where the class are null you have to do something like this : (myClass == null) ? "" : "Hello Wordl"

Comment: I found a solution to that problem. It doesn't skip assigning values, but it assigns null to strings and 0 to ints.
someVariable = (dr["someColumn"] != DBNull.Value) ? dr["someColumn"].ToString() : someVariable;

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the  DataTable and find not null values in all rows. You need to check against DBNull.

```
var dtRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList();
var rowsWithoutNullValue = dtRows.Where(x => x.Any(y => y != null || y != DBNull.Value)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "skip assigning a value" you mean you want to discard the `null`s altogether, then just run

```
.Where(x => x != null)
```

first, and then do your transform.